# Countdown of letters with reactor

Tags: python, twisted

I am learning twisted and have developed a simple python script that should count down each letter of the alphabet and stop the reactor when it gets to `z`. However, I am getting the following error:

> assert builtins.callable(callable), f"{callable} is not callable"
> builtins.AssertionError: a is not callable

Here's my script:

```
class Countletters(object):
    letters = list( map(chr, range(97, 123)) )

    def countletters(self):
        for l in self.letters:
            if l  == 'z':
                rector.stop()
            else:
                print(l)
                reactor.callLater(1, l)
from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.callWhenRunning(Countletters().countletters)
print('Start countdown')
reactor.run()
print('Stop countdown')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there - the problem is the `callLater` part.

`callLater` expects a function, something "Callable", but you give it `l`; a string (the current letter).

Try this for an example:
I pass `functools.partial(print, l)` to `callLater` which basically creates a callable object, which will simply do `print(l)` when called.

```
import functools

from twisted.internet import reactor

class Countletters(object):
    letters = list(map(chr, range(97, 123)))

    def countletters(self):
        for l in self.letters:
            if l == 'z':
                reactor.stop()
            else:
                print(l)
                reactor.callLater(1, functools.partial(print, l))


reactor.callWhenRunning(Countletters().countletters)
print('Start countdown')
reactor.run()
print('Stop countdown')
```

Comment: Ah I see, then I could have also just done `self.countletters` in `callLater`. However, I expected the programme to read one letter at a time, instead it just prints everything out.